# How to print <a href > tag in a servlet?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

So I get the *PrintWriter* in the following manner:

```
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

In the JSP I just append the response like so (where data is the response):

```
         $('#venueList').empty(); 

         $('#venueList').append(data);
```

And try to print the following `<a>` tag , I know it's not nice but I need a quick solution:

```
  out.println("<tr><td>" + v.getOther() + "</td></tr>");
  out.println("<tr><td><a href=\"VenueServlet?action=edit&userId="+v.getId()+">Update</a></td></tr>");
  out.println("</table>");
```

My problem is that the link does not call,
for example: `VenueServlet?action=edit&userId=66`
it tries to continue like:
`/VenueServlet?action=edit&userId=66>Update</a></td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 3):

You never close the quote of the `href` attribute.

The output itself is enough to diagnose this–the href just keeps going:

```
out.println("<tr><td><a href=\"VenueServlet?action=edit&userId="+v.getId()+"\">Update</a></td></tr>");
```

Yet another reason why not to generate HTML on the Java side. Consider using `String.format`, too; it's much easier (IMO) to read this mess when you don't have to worry about string math.

Also, if the ID is coming from the browser, you'll probably want to escape it appropriately.